# Assign char16_t with character literal codepoints outside of basic multilingual plane

Tags: c++, unicode, language-lawyer, utf-16, string-literals

In a talk I watched on Unicode earlier today, there was some confusion about what should happen when you attempt to assign a character literal that's too long to be represented by the `char16_t` type.  The presenter says that based on a reading of the standard, the program ought to be ill-formed, but that gcc accepts it anyway.  He didn't clarify, and Youtube doesn't allow me to ask questions.

My own testing confirms that the following code is accepted by g++-4.8 and g++-4.9. (with warnings.)

```
int main() {
  char16_t a = u'\U0001F378';
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cb2206660407a8d
https://eval.in/188979

On the other hand clang 3.4 generates an error.

Which compiler is correct?  I can't find the chapter and verse for this.

Additional small question, the character literal section §2.14.3 does not mention the `\u` and `\U` escape sequences in the W-grammar or in the section body.  Is this an oversight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is ill-formed and should fail to compile.

> **2.14.3/2** A character literal that begins with the letter u, such as u’y’, is a character literal of type char16_t. The
>   value of a char16_t literal containing a single c-char is equal to its ISO 10646 code point value, provided that
>   the code point is representable with a single 16-bit code unit. (That is, provided it is a basic multi-lingual
>   plane code point.) If the value is not representable within 16 bits, **the program is ill-formed**...

Emphasis mine.

`\u` and `\U` are not escape sequences within the meaning of **2.14.3**. They are universal character names, described in **2.3/2**. They are not limited to character and string literals, but may appear [anywhere in the program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86f0654b3668bbbc):

```
int main() {
    int \u0410 = 42;
    return \u0410;
}
```

`\u0410` is `A`, aka Cyrillic Capital Letter A.

Comment: I can't believe that I was in the proper section and completely missed it. :/  Thanks.  And also, universal character names, I guess they're required, but man, making a proper IDE for C++ just got a hell of a lot more challenging.  I assume the translation is done during tokenizing like trigraphs, which makes for interesting obfuscated code opportunities.

Comment: Phases of translation, including the details of handling trigraphs and universal character names, are described in **2.2/1**